# Live streaming endpoint doesn't start with CDN in Azure media services

Tags: azure, azure-media-services, azure-cdn

The live streaming endpoint doesn't start with CDN features in Azure media services of [Azure Portal](https://portal.azure.com).

For example, I added a new streaming endpoint with standard CDN pricing tier in Azure portal with the following fields.
[image]

After creating the streaming endpoint, I tried to start to run. But its status is "starting" for 10~15 mins, then it stops. Does anyone know how to run the streaming endpoint with CDN features?

Comment: You can refer to [Manage streaming endpoints with the Azure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/previous/media-services-portal-manage-streaming-endpoints), [Stream content with CDN integration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/latest/stream-scale-streaming-cdn-concept) and [Streaming Endpoints (Origin) in Azure Media Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/latest/stream-streaming-endpoint-concept)

Comment: Thank you for your comment. But I still cannot find the solution to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

More than likely there is a conflict with an existing CDN endpoint that is causing the Media Services streaming endpoint to not be able to start.

When a Media Services streaming endpoint starts, a couple of things happen. The AMS streaming endpoint checks to see if it is CDN enabled. If not, it simply starts. If the CDN is enabled on the streaming endpoint:

1. A new CDN endpoint is created within the CDN profile that is registered for the AMS streaming endpoint.
2. The DNS name of the AMS streaming endpoint is handed over to the CDN endpoint as a custom domain name.
3. The AMS streaming endpoint is given a new name of 'cdn--*{streamingEndpointName}*' and the CDN endpoint uses this for the *Origin hostname*.
4. The AMS streaming endpoint attempts to start.

When the AMS streaming endpoint is stopped the CDN endpoint is deleted since it is no longer needed.  If this delete does not happen correctly this can cause a name conflict the next time the AMS streaming endpoint start is attempted.  In your case this is likely what has happened.  Most likely all you need to do is to check the AzureMediaStreamingPlatformCdnProfile-StandardVerizon CDN profile in your account to see if there is a CDN endpoint that remains.  If so, delete the CDN endpoint that has a custom host name the same as your streaming endpoint name.  If you still have trouble, please open a support case.